# Jenkinsfile - use Global properties in post

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Here is my Jenkinsfile for multi-branch pipeline project:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {

        stage('MASTER build') {
            when { 
                branch 'master'
            }
            steps {
                sh 'mvn -P x clean deploy'
            }
        }

        stage('BRANCH build') {
            when { 
                not { branch 'master' }
            }
            steps {
                sh 'mvn -P x clean package' 
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        failure {
            emailext "${EMAIL_TEMPLATE}"
        }
    }
}
```

When I build my project in Jenkis following error occurs:

```
WorkflowScript: 26: Step does not take a single required parameter - use named parameters instead @ line 26, column 13.
               emailext "${EMAIL_TEMPLATE}"
```

Why I cant use **EMAIL_TEMPLATE** global variable containing all **emailext** definition?

Comment: i think it must be something like `failure {
            emailext body:"${EMAIL_TEMPLATE}"
        }`

Comment: I noticed that inserted a value of EMAIL_TEMPLATE is String and it was a problem with changing e.g. recipientProviders for Class type :)